# NodeJs- Series of nested API call asynchronously

Tags: node.js, node-async

I am facing issue in a payment transaction. First API calls an external API, which collects money from customer to merchant. Upon success of first API call , I need to invoke another API call instantaneously which transfers part of collected money by merchant to third party. I am not sure, NodeJS async - series/waterfall method is the right choice.

- **Scenario A** - First API call throw error. Entire transaction fails and customer would be asked to re-try transaction.
- **Scenario B** - First one successful and second one is successful. No Issue.
- **Scenario C** - First one successful and second one throws error. Entire transaction ( using series/waterfall) would be failed and customer would be asked to retry, but merchant has already got money because first transaction was successful.

Please help me, what would be right way to do it using Express NodeJS? Share some code as well if possible.

Comment: This isn't a single question and is really a pretty broad matter.  You can investigate a module like `async` that has functionality like you describe but I'm not really sure how to help beyond that advice.

Answer (score 1):

Due to latest practices it's better to use some Promises library like `Q` or `bluebird` etc.

```
Q.fcall(promisedStep1)
  .then(promisedStep2)      
  .then(function (value2) {
    // Do something if success
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // Handle any error from above steps and revert transaction if needed
  })
```

Also I'd think on the part where you'd be able to rollback your transaction, in most cases it should be implemented and funds must be returned at some point.

FYI: Latest stable nodejs version supports Promises by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');    
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

router.get('payment', middleware1, middleware2, successfull);

// handle errors
app.use(function(err, req, res) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.send(err.message).end();
});

function middleware1(req, res, next) {
  try {
    // ...
    next();
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  } 
}

function middleware2(req, res, next) {
  try {
    // ...
    next();
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  } 
}

function successfull(req, res) {
  res.status(201).end(); 
}
```